# Change the content of a div based on selection from dropdown menu with first option visible with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm setting up a select button to change the content beneath it. I've found out how to change the content below, however I need one of the options shown before any selection begins.

[Default Selection 1]

displays: nothing

```js
document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("change", function() {
  "use strict";
  var vis = document.querySelector(".vis"),
      target = document.getElementById(this.value);
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = "inv";
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = "vis";
  }
});
```

```css
.inv {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="target">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
 <option value="content_1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="content_2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="content_3">Option 3</option>
 <select>

<div id="content_1" class="inv">Content 1</div>
<div id="content_2" class="inv">Content 2</div>
<div id="content_3" class="inv">Content 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the preselected option and, add `vis` and remove `inv` class from it

```js
document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("change", function() {
  "use strict";
  var vis = document.querySelector(".vis"),
      target = document.getElementById(this.value);
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = "inv";
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = "vis";
  }
});
```

```css
.inv {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="target">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
 <option value="content_1 vis" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
 <option value="content_2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="content_3">Option 3</option>
 <select>

<div id="content_1" class="vis">Content 1</div>
<div id="content_2" class="inv">Content 2</div>
<div id="content_3" class="inv">Content 3</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as now it always displays the selected option.

Comment: For this to work, you need to add the `vis` class to the selected option